# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Tags: iis-7.5

I reinstalled Windows and am now configuring everything to get my machine up and running again. I'm receiving this error when navigating to www.mysite.com:
[image]

I looked at various forums and have given folder c:\dropbpx\inetpub\mysite full permissions for IIS_IUSRS, IUSR, Everyone AND NETWORK SERVICE, but I keep getting the error.
I've also given full permissions for IIS_IUSRS on applicationhost.config in %WINDIR%\System32\inetsrv\config\

Also when I via IIS go to my website and click on 'authentication' I get the error:
There was an error while performing this operation.
Details:
Filename: \?\C:\Dropbox\inetpub\mysite\web.config
Error:

Application pool of my website is set to ASP.NET v4.0

See here my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->

<configuration>


<connectionStrings>
<add name="conn1" connectionString="data source=(local);Initial Catalog=tt;User Id=sa;Password=dfsdf3454sdg;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="5000000" />
  </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>

<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />  
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="60" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".MyCookie" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60" cookieless="AutoDetect" loginUrl="/login/" protection="All" defaultUrl="/">
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1" />
  </forms>
</authentication>
<roleManager domain="192.168.0.103" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookieTimeout="60" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All" defaultProvider="AccessRoleProvider" createPersistentCookie="false" maxCachedResults="25">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AccessRoleProvider" connectionStringName="conn1" applicationName="/wedding" type="Samples.AccessProviders.AccessRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="AccessMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AccessMembershipProvider" type="Samples.AccessProviders.AccessMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="conn1" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/wedding" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
  </providers>
</membership>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<!-- SEO-friendly URLS for IIS 7.0 (if you're using IIS 6.0 see above) -->
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add type="aspnetforum.ForumSEOHttpModule, aspnetforum" name="ForumSEOHttpModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="ScriptCombiner" verb="POST,GET" path="ScriptCombiner.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="ScriptCombiner, App_Code" />
</handlers>
<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
</security> 
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="default.aspx" />
    <add value="Default.htm" />
    <add value="Default.asp" />
    <add value="index.htm" />
    <add value="index.html" />
    <add value="iisstart.htm" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".kml" mimeType="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="VirtueleKassaWebServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="VirtueleKassaWebServiceSoap1" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://secure.virtuelekassa.nl/webservice/VirtueleKassaWebservice.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="VirtueleKassaWebServiceSoap" contract="virtuelekassa.VirtueleKassaWebServiceSoap" name="VirtueleKassaWebServiceSoap" />
</client>
  <services>
      <service name="RestService.weddingservice">
          <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.Iweddingservice" />
      </service>
  </services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

What else can it be?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the web.config file?

Comment: I added my web.config. it's however the exact same as I used before I reinstalled windows, so there should not be a problem in there.

Comment: I have set up a similar configuration as the one you mention (**IIS 7.5**, using the **Web.config** you posted, downloading the necessary dependencies for it to compile, and setting the IIS website root folder to the one containing all this) and I'm not getting any errors. I didn't have to set up any folder permissions or anything. I would try deleting all folders from `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`,  although it's an extremely long shot, it sometimes does the trick.

Comment: Damn...that's what I get for leaving out parts of the web.config I don't deem relevant: it was the urlrewrite section I have in the web.config! I installed it (http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=urlrewrite2) and now it works...thanks for you effort!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Never leave out parts of the web.config you don't deem relevant: it was the urlrewrite section I have in the web.config! I installed it (http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=urlrewrite2) and now it works.

Answer (score 5):

Check for the following IIS features are On.(Application Development Features)

[image]

If features under Application Development Features are not on turn it on from Windows Features on off from control panel.

Answer (score 0):

> Thats because you have not registered the ASP in IIS.
>
> Go to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 and execute
>   aspnet_regiis.exe
>
> Go to IIS, expand server, click Application Pools. If it doesn't
>   contain "ASP.NET v4.0" and "ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" files, ASP is not
>   registered in IIS.
>
> Take command prompt, go to
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 location. Type
>   aspnet_regiis -i
>
> Now it will show that ASP is getting registered. After it is
>   completed, you can see "ASP.NET v4.0" and "ASP.NET v4.0 Classic" files
>   in IIS under Application Pool